# Error running Net::Async::OpenTracing on the latest stable Perl 5.32.0

Tags: perl, perl-module

have anyone tried to use the Perl's Net::Async::OpenTracing module? I try to run the sample script [exactly as is given on metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Async-OpenTracing/lib/Net/Async/OpenTracing.pod) on the latest stable perl-5.32.0 release (run thru perlbrew), but it throws the error below. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

> Error:
>
> ======
>
> Can't call method "span" on an undefined value at
> /home/myUser/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/OpenTracing/SpanProxy.pm
> line 81.
>
> (in cleanup) Can't call method "finish_span" on an undefined value at
> /home/myUser/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/OpenTracing/Span.pm
> line 192.
>
> Argument "49da55ebcdc914bbd7145f8bd5e1ce6b" isn't numeric in pack at
> /home/myUser/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/Net/Async/OpenTracing.pm
> line 196.
>
> Argument "da4ca045cfee6586" isn't numeric in pack at
> /home/myUser/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/Net/Async/OpenTracing.pm
> line 196.

Comment: Both those reported github issues have been sitting there since March and April but no feedback!

Comment: I can confirm this error on Ubuntu 20.04, perl version 5.30. For some reason `$parent->tracer` is undefined on [line 81](https://metacpan.org/release/OpenTracing/source/lib/OpenTracing/SpanProxy.pm#L81)

Comment: Thanks for confirming the error Hakon. I run Perl 5.32 on CentOS 7.